# Difference between the translations of ‘loneliness’

Tags: difference, noun

I have translated *loneliness* into German. There are three translations for that. What is the difference between these three words?

Einsamkeit f,
Verlassenheit f,
Vereinsamung Nf

Comment: Hast Du geschaut, zu was eine Rückübersetzung führt?

Comment: @userunknown What does *Rückübersetztung* mean?

Comment: @AdInfinitum: »Rück« = »back« or »reverse«. »Übersetzung« = »translation«. So »Rückübersetzung« = »reverse translation«, i.e. Translation of the result of the translation back into the original language.

Answer (score 4):

*Einsamkeit* is the most general of all the nouns in the question. It has the most general meaning of *the state of loneliness,* i.e. nobody else being around. What the reasons are is irrelevant, *Einsamkeit* can be used.

> Beduinen ziehen tagelang durch die Einsamkeit der Wüste.

*Vereinsamung* refers more to the *process of isolation* and is generally used in social (science) contexts. Often the sentences it is used in imply pity for the people being isolated or isolating themselves (but that is not necessary).

> Erst kommt der Alkohol, dann die soziale Vereinsamung.

*Verlassenheit* is a word I have rarely encountered to date, but [dwds.de](http://dwds.de/r?corpus=kern;q=Verlassenheit) provides sufficient proof of its existence. It is derived from the adjective *verlassen* which means *left alone* (or the correspondig verb *to leave).* Contrary to *Vereinsamung,* which describes a person’s state, *Verlassenheit* would more typically be used to describe their feelings.

> Nachdem die Anderen gegangen waren, ergriff ihn ein Gefühl der Verlassenheit.

Answer (score 2):

`Einsamkeit` is a state not referring to anything.
But`Verlassenheit` means you where not lonely before, so others **left** you alone. Both are like a feeling.
`Vereinsamung` describes a social isolation (maybe like the loneliness of more persons). It is more a science word I think.
The common translation would be `Einsamkeit`.

Answer (score 0):

I have read an [article](https://www.welt.de/gesundheit/psychologie/article122448909/Was-Alleinsein-von-Einsamkeit-unterscheidet.html) about this topic. In this article, it differentiates *Einsamkeit* from *Alleinsein*.

The article basically says that these words seem very similar but actually mean very different at their cores.

*Alleinsein* is what you understand from *loneliness*. Even if you want some people around you but because of some reason, this does not happen and you are alone.

In contrast to *Alleinsein*, *Einsamkeit* means that you have people (your family, your friends, your colleagues etc.) around you but you still feel yourself alone. You think and/or feel that they do not understand you well.